# How to keep jquery drop down hover content open when hovering the next li class

Tags: jquery, html

I uploaded a jquery drop down menu from a site and i was wanting to know if this is possible and if so, how?
Currently when you hover over any of the 3 main li classes, a drop down menu expands below each one, then if you hover off the div that opens or hover to another li class the menu closes and new content appears. I would like to have it so, once you hover and open any of them, then if your mouse over the next one, the entire container doesn't contract, rather adjust for the new content for that new li .  Example of what i'd like is the [Nike.com](http://www.nike.com/)
menu, where anytime your mouse is on the nav area, the last drop content remains, and if you hover across a new menu item, the menu doesn't collapse, it adjust itself for the new content.

I set up a demo test on jsfiddle here  http://jsfiddle.net/R7aTq/

```
$(function(){

    $('#navigation_horiz').naviDropDown({
        dropDownWidth: '300px'
    });

    $('#navigation_vert').naviDropDown({
        dropDownWidth: '300px',
        orientation: 'vertical'
    });
});
```

Comment: anyone have any ideas on how to achieve this ? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution I came up with: http://jsfiddle.net/JeremyGood/R7aTq/198/

You might want to add some animation. Also, if you played around with absolute positioning, you could have the dropdowns be the same width of the navbar.

Of course, we've essentially just rewritten the dropdown logic of the plugin. At some point, it just becomes your own custom menu code.

```
$(function(){

    $('#navigation_horiz').naviDropDown({
        dropDownWidth: '300px'
    });

    $('#navigation_vert').naviDropDown({
        dropDownWidth: '300px',
        orientation: 'vertical'
    });

    var olddropdown = null;

    $("#navigation_horiz>ul>li").unbind('mouseout');
    $("#navigation_horiz>ul>li").unbind('mouseover');
    $("#navigation_horiz>ul>li").bind("mouseout", function(event) {
         olddropdown = $(this).find(".dropdown");
    });
    $("#navigation_horiz>ul>li").bind("mouseover", function(event) {
        $(this).find(".dropdown").css('display', 'block');
        if (olddropdown != null) {
            olddropdown.css('display', 'none');
            olddropdown = null;
        }
    });
    $("#navigation_horiz>ul").bind("mouseout", function(event) {
        olddropdown.css('display', 'none');
        olddropdown = null;
    });
});
```